# Haskell Prelude.head error, empty list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

My code is throwing an empty list error. When I run:

```
makeAgent :: Agent -> [Agent] -> Agent
makeAgent (Agent func n _) agents = (Agent func (n++(show $ length $ sameNames n agents)) empty) --appends number to name to differentiate agents
    where sameNames n agents = filter (findName n) agents
          findName n1 (Agent _ n2 _) = (slice 0 3 n1) == (slice 0 3 n2) --ignore the suffix
          empty = head $ getEmpty (positions agents) (fst $ getGrid agents) --getGrid returns a tuple, but currently assume to be a square

baseline :: [Interaction] -> Float
baseline int = (fromIntegral total)/len
  where total = sum sums
        sums = map snd (showSums int)
        agents = nub  $ map (\(Interaction a1 a2 _ ) ->  a2) int
        len  = fromIntegral $ length agents

reproduce :: Float -> [Interaction] -> [Agent]  --so baseline isn't recalulated every time
reproduce _ [] = []
reproduce base interaction = winners ++ [newAgent] ++ reproduce base (tail interaction)
    where agents = nub $ concat $ map (\(Interaction a1 a2 _ ) -> a1:a2:[]) interaction
          winners = [a | a <- agents, (sumAgent interaction a) >= (round base)]
          newAgent = makeAgent (head winners) winners


main = do
    output "Length" (fromIntegral $ length int)
    output "Baseline" base
    output "Agents" agents
    output "Sums" (showSums int)
    output "winners" winners
    output "NeAgent" (makeAgent (head winners)winners)
    output "New Agents" (reproduce base int)

    where agents = generate 4
          int = playRound agents 20
          base = baseline int
          winners = [a | a <- agents, (sumAgent int a) >= (round base)]
```

What this reproduce, the main function, should be doing is generating a new agent based on whether their parents "fitness"  is over a certain level, then run the same function with all but that agent in the list of agents.

It outputs:

```
Length: 16
Baseline: 280.0
Agents: [c_pavlov(-1,-1),c_titForTat(-1,0),c_sucker(-1,1),b_grim(0,-1)]
Sums: [("c_pavlov",280),("c_titForTat",280),("c_sucker",280),("b_grim",280)]
winners: [c_pavlov(-1,-1),c_titForTat(-1,0),c_sucker(-1,1),b_grim(0,-1)]
NeAgent: c_pavlov1(0,0)
prisoners: Prelude.head: empty list
```

When I call reproduce, it throws the prelude.head empty list error, and the winners,agent, and int lists are all non-empty, so it may be an edge case error on the last iteration of the recursion. Why is this happening?

Comment: You don't show us the line where it prints "prisoners"

Comment: That't the name of the file, so that's what it prefaces before the error.

Comment: Please  provide the full source.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is relatively simple: Simply **do not use** `head` and `tail` in Haskell programs. (While there are a few situation where it is reasonable to do so, it's best to assume in the beginning that there aren't.)

Instead, use pattern matching. Usually, you will always want to properly pattern match on both the empty list and the non-empty list, like this:

```
fun :: [Something] -> ...
fun []       = ...
fun (x : xs) = ... -- x is head, xs is tail
```

This way, you are forced to deal with the error, *and* you know that referring to `x` and `xs` cannot fail anymore, because the list has already been determined to be non-empty.

If you have lots of lists in your program that should never be empty, then you have to manually keep track of these conditions (and should at least *document* them). But even then, it's better to pattern match in a `let`-binding like this

```
(winner : _) = ...
```

and then refer to `winner` as the head of that list later, because you will get an error message involving the line number where the pattern match failed.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't exactly say where the error is occurring. Presumably it's when you call <s>`tail`</s> `head` without checking if the list is empty.

If that's the case, you can fix it with a pattern match for an empty `interaction` list.

Otherwise, you'll need to give more info on the error.

*(edited: replaced tail with head)*

Comment: sine the error is `Prelude.head` I have to say this is unlikely

Comment: Ah! I was looking for an error message in the original post and didn't see it. Still, the advice (use pattern matching) remains the same, though more fully expressed in the answer by kosmikus.