# Function containing head and tail functions throws empty list error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying the solve the first question in [Advent of Code 2017](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/1), and come up with the following solution to calculate the needed value:

```
checkRepetition :: [Int] -> Bool
checkRepetition [] = False
checkRepetition (x:xs)
 | x == ( head xs ) = True
 | otherwise = False

test :: [Int] -> Int
test [] = 0
test [x] = 0
test xs
 | checkRepetition xs == True = ((head xs)*a) + (test (drop a xs))
 | otherwise = test (tail xs)
  where
   a = (go (tail xs)) + 1
   go :: [Int] -> Int
   go [] = 0
   go xs
    | checkRepetition xs == True = 1 + ( go (tail xs) )
    | otherwise = 0
```

However, when I give an input that contains repetitive numbers such as `[1,3,3]`, it gives the error

> *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

However, for 1.5 hours, I couldn't figure out exactly where this error is generated. I mean any function that is used in `test` function have a definition for `[]`, but still it throws this error, so what is the problem ?

Note that, I have checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285439/haskell-prelude-head-error-empty-list) question, and in the given answer, it is advised not to use `head` and `tail` functions, but I have tested those function for various inputs, and they do not throw any error, so what exactly is the problem ?

I would appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: What if you pass it a singleton-list, like `[4]`. You call `tail` on `xs`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I get simply an empty list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem And it does now throw any error when I try it on ghci.

Comment: The immediate problem is in `checkRepetition`, so you should test if that function does what it's supposed to. More generally, though, the problem is that you should not use `head` and `tail` at all. Just use pattern matching. Furthermore, `foo == True` is the same as `foo`.

Comment: @kosmikus Thanks for your comment; however, what you said has been said in the linked answer, and as I have stated, what is the reason for that ? I mean those function does not throw any error when they are tested on ghci manually, so why should they give any error inside to code ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: I mean the `checkrepition` function, so `checkrepititon [2]`.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Of course it's *possible* to use `head` and `tail` in such a way that the program does what you want. The question is whether you *should*. The point is that you'll easily miss a case if you start using them, as you did in `checkRepetition`. If you use pattern matching, testing for non-empty list and accessing head and tail are combined in such a way that you *cannot* make a mistake, which is much better.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What exactly are you referring to by `[2]` ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Willem is referring to the list `[2]`. `checkRepetition [2]` will lead to the evaluation of `2 == head []`, which is where the error comes from. Use pattern matching instead of `head` and `tail`. (Patterns can be arbitrarily complex – `x:y:xs` matches a list with at least two elements, for instance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, the issue is here:

```
checkRepetition (x:xs)
 | x == ( head xs ) = True
```

`xs` is not guaranteed to be a non-empty list (a one-element list is written as `x:[]`, so that `(x:xs)` pattern matches that `xs = []`) and calling `head` on an empty list is a runtime error.

You can deal with this by changing your pattern to only match on a 2+ element list.

```
checkRepetition []        = False
checkRepetition [_]       = False
checkRepetition (x1:x2:_) = x1 == x2
-- No need for the alternations on this function, by the way.
```

---

That said, your algorithm seems needlessly complex. All you have to do is check if the *next* value is equal, and if so then add the current value to the total. Assuming you can get your `String -> [Int]` on your own, consider something like:

```
filteredSum :: [Int] -> Int
filteredSum []            = 0  -- by definition, zero- and one-element lists
filteredSum [_]           = 0  -- cannot produce a sum, so special case them here
filteredSum xss@(first:_) = go xss
  where
  -- handle all recursive cases
  go (x1:xs@(x2:_)) | x1 == x2   = x1 + go xs
                    | otherwise  =      go xs
  -- base case
  go [x]            | x == first = x  -- handles last character wrapping
                    | otherwise  = 0  -- and if it doesn't wrap
  -- this should be unreachable
  go []             = 0
```

For what it's worth, I think it's better to work in the Maybe monad and operate over `Maybe [Int] -> Maybe Int`, but luckily that's easy since Maybe is a functor.

```
digitToMaybeInt :: Char -> Maybe Int
digitToMaybeInt '0' = Just 0
digitToMaybeInt '1' = Just 1
digitToMaybeInt '2' = Just 2
digitToMaybeInt '3' = Just 3
digitToMaybeInt '4' = Just 4
digitToMaybeInt '5' = Just 5
digitToMaybeInt '6' = Just 6
digitToMaybeInt '7' = Just 7
digitToMaybeInt '8' = Just 8
digitToMaybeInt '9' = Just 9
digitToMaybeInt _   = Nothing

maybeResult :: Maybe Int
maybeResult = fmap filteredSum . traverse digitToMaybeInt $ input

result :: Int
result = case maybeResult of
         Just x  -> x
         Nothing -> 0
-- this is equivalent to `maybe 0 id maybeResult`
```

Comment: Your "fixed" `checkRepetition` still doesn't work on singleton lists...

Comment: @DanielWagner whoops, oversight. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AdamSmith;however, even though I appreciate the sentiment, posting solution to the main problem that I'm trying solve in order to learn prevents me from reading your answer :)

Comment: FYI, apparently I misunderstood the problem, so after realising this, I arrived at the almost exactly the same answer as you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the link. I went there first to glean the purpose.
I assume the input will be a string. The helper function below constructs a numeric list to be used to sum if predicate is True, that is, the zipped values are equal, that is, each number compared to each successive number (the pair).

The helper function 'nl' invokes the primary function 'invcap' Inverse Captcha with a list of numbers.

The nl function is a list comprehension. The invcap function is a list comprehension. Perhaps the logic in this question is at fault. Overly complicated logic is more likely to introduce errors. Proofs are very much easier when logic is not cumbersome.

The primary function "invcap"

```
invcap l = sum [ x | (x,y) <- zip l $ (tail l) ++ [head l], x == y]
```

The helper function that converts a string to a list of digits and invokes invcap with a list of numeric digits.

```
nl cs = invcap [ read [t] :: Int | t <- cs]
```

Invocation examples
Prelude> nl "91212129" ......
9 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' 
Prelude> nl "1122" ......
3

Comment: This handles the singleton input.  > nl "1" ... 1 ' ' ' ' ' ' "invcap [2]  .... 2 ' ' ' ' ' ' invcap [] ...... 0 -- this function makes any input list into two lists so continues to work given thoughtless inputs.